# リンクリストのメソッドをテンプレートを使い定義したい

Tags: c++

リンクリストのメソッドをテンプレートを使い定義したいです。自分は以下のようなコードを作りましたが、ある問題が発生しました。それは、addHead()をソースファイル（cppファイル）に定義すると正常にコンパイルできないのです。しかしながら、まったく同じものをヘッダーファイル（hファイル）に定義すると正常にコンパイルできるようになるのです。
また、ソースファイルに定義すると次のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル "public: void __thiscall List<int>::addHead(int)" (?addHead@?$List@H@@QAEXH@Z) が関数 _main で参照されました
lab9.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 件の未解決の外部参照
```

私の考えはLinkクラスがList.cppでうまく参照されてないのではないかと思っているのですが、何も根拠はありません。
何とかしてソースファイルにリンクリストのメソッドを定義したいのですがどなたかアドバイスお願いしましす。
追記：CLionをつかってコードしました。

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int size = 5;
    List<int> numbers;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        numbers.addHead(i);
    }

    cout << numbers.showList();
    return 0;
}
```

List.h

```
#include <string>

using std::string;


template <typename T>
class Link
{
private:
    T value;
    Link* next;
public:
    //constructor
    Link(T value, Link* next = nullptr): value(value), next(next){}
    //destructor
    virtual ~Link(){}
    //return value
    T getValue(){return this->value;}
    //return next
    Link* getNext(){return this->next;}
    //set next
    void setNext(Link* next){this->next = next;}
};

template <typename T>
class List
{
private:
    Link<T>* head;
public:
    List():head(nullptr){}
    //virtual ~List();
    void addHead(T value);

    //for testing
    
    string showList()
    {
        string buffer = "";
        if(head == nullptr)
        {
            buffer = "Nothing in the List";
        }
        else
        {
            buffer = "Head -> ";
            for(Link<T>* currentLink = head; currentLink; currentLink = currentLink->getNext())
            {
                buffer += std::to_string(currentLink->getValue());
                buffer += " -> ";
            }
            buffer += "nullptr";
        }
        return buffer;
    }
    
};
```

List.cpp

```
#include "List.h"


template <typename T>
void List<T>::addHead(T value)
{
    Link<T>* theLink;
    theLink = new Link<T>(value);
    theLink->setNext(head);
    head = theLink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ご想像通り「List.cpp」がコンパイルもリンクもされていないのではないでしょうか。

・対処方法は構築環境によって異なりますので、それを追記するとより適切な回答がえられると予想できます。

例として、Visual Studioを使っている場合の追加の手順の概要を示します。

1. ソリューションエクスプローラの当該プロジェクトを右クリックする。
2. コンテキストメニューから「追加(D)」の「既存の項目(G)」を選択する。
3. 「既存の項目の追加」DLGで「List.cpp」を選択して「OK」
4. ソリューションエクスプローラに「List.cpp」が表示されます。

確認出来たら「リビルド」してみましょう。

Comment: 知識不足で申し訳ありません。構築環境が具体的に何を指すのかが分かっていません。しかし、CLionというものを使って作りました。CLionは構築環境に含まれるのでしょうか。

Comment: 構築環境です。日本語のマニュアルにはプロジェクトにソースを追加する方法も既存のソースをプロジェクトに追加する方法も説明されているようなので、一読されることをお勧めします。

Comment: いろいろ調べてみた結果、リンクされていても自分のやりたかったことはできないそうです。なので、ヘッダーファイル上で定義するしかないみたいです。不可能な質問をしてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。しかしながら、この回答の件を詳しく調べた結果、不可能ということが分かりましたので、とてもありがたく思います。手間をとらせてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。